# Is it possible to add audio at the end of an existing audio stream?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, audio-recording, libavcodec, libavformat

I managed to implement my decoding and encoding audio class with libavformat. 
I can create and read mp3, ogg, ...

Now, I'd like to add a function to "record at the end of an existing audio file". 
Ie : add some new frames (of audio data) to the end of an existing stream. (my files are only audio files with 1 and only stream).

To sum up I triyed this with no success :

```
av_register_all(); 
avformat_open_input(&AVFormatContext , filename, NULL, NULL) 
avformat_find_stream_info(AVFormatContext , NULL) 
audio_stream_idx = av_find_best_stream(AVFormatContext , AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, NULL, 0); 
AVStream = AVFormatContext ->streams[audio_stream_idx_]; 
AVCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AVStream->codec->codec_id); 
avcodec_open2(AVStream->codec, AVCodec, NULL); 
AVFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame(); 

... 

loop 
{    avcodec_encode_audio2(AVStream->codec, &AVPacket, AVFrame, &got_packet_); 
     av_write_frame(AVFormatContext, &AVPacket); 
} 

...
```

And it crash on the first av_write_frame.

I see 3 possible reasons, but I don't know how to do it :

- The input and output file are the same. How am I supposed to init my AVFormatContext and AVOutputFormat ?

  avformat_alloc_output_context2(&AVFormatContext , NULL, NULL, filename); 
     AVOutputFormat = AVFormatContext ->oformat; 
     avformat_open_input(&AVFormatContext , filename, NULL, NULL)
- When I got my AVStream, do I have to seek to its end ? How ?
- Do I have to use avio_open(&AVFormatContext->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE); ?

Thanks in advance. 
I found nothing in the samples about that, but if you have some samples or ideas ... :)

Comment: You can merge two MP3 or OGG audio files by simple binary concatenation. This is how audio streaming works: stream is just a bunch of short MP3 files.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find a solution to my problem, I will use you suggestion as a workaround.